# Defining mailer in sorcery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am building a rails app using sorcery. When I go to users/new, there is an Argument Error stating
"To use reset_password submodule, you must define a mailer (config.reset_password_mailer = YourMailerClass)"

Went into config/initializers/sorcery.rb and included code
`user.reset_password_mailer = UserMailer` but I am still receiving the error.
Within the UserMailer class, I defined reset_password_email method

```
 def reset_password_email(user)
    @user = User.find user.id
    @url  = edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_password_token)
      mail(:to => user.email,
           :subject => "Your password has been reset")
end
```

and updated the sorcery.rb file

```
user.reset_password_email_method_name = :reset_password_email
```

I am still receiving the same error message.

In the Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to products_url, notice: "Signed Up!"
        else
            render "new"
        end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

And my User model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  has_many :projects

  validates :password, confirmation: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you followed the [Sorcery docs](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Reset-password) to configure the mailer. But keep in mind that `config/initializers/sorcery.rb`, like all of the files in `config/initializers` will only be processed when the application starts.

It looks like your configuration is correct, and I get the same error if I run the application before I add the configuration, but it does work for me after restarting the Rails server.